# Navitating in WebBrowser / Windows Phone 7. Wrong redirecting

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have Windows Phone 7 project. I put into project content new folder "help" and few html files like "index.html" etc.

```
help/index.html
help/index2.html
```

I can go to my index.html page with

```
Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("help/index.html", UriKind.Relative));
```

but when I am in index.html and Click into Table of contents I just have blank site with text "index2.html".

```
<td class="nav-item"><a href="index2.html">Table of contents</a></td>
```

What should I do - change  or setup WebBrowser (base, source or other properties)?

Comment: Can you share content of index2.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone **7** does not support relative navigation or referencing of files that are in the XAP.

To be able to use HTML files you'll need to first copy them to IsolatedStorage and show/browse/navigate them there.

Comment: As you command I use http://technodave.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/moving-files-from-xap-to-isolated-storage-for-local-html-content-on-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 1):

Follow the example line by line. Try to create a hello world from this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431811%28v=vs.105%29.aspx